# firebase error reference.push failed: fist argument contains undefined in property 'email'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I made a sign up, the data in the authentication firebase entered but an error occurred when the data was entered into the database where the value of the email was undefined. Please help

```
    dispatch(requestSignUp());
    myFirebase
    .auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(
        myFirebase.database().ref('users').push({
            email: email.value,
        })).then(user=>{
        dispatch(receiveSignUp(user));
    }).catch(error=>{
        dispatch(signinError());
    })
}
```

this sign up component

```
class SignUp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {email:'', password:''}
    }

    onSubmit = event =>{
        event.preventDefault();     
        const {dispatch} = this.props;
        const {email, password} = this.state;
        dispatch(signUp(email, password));
        window.confirm("data berhasil ditambahkan klik signin")
    }
    onEmailChange = ({target})=>{
        this.setState({email:target.value});
    }

    onPasswordChange = ({target})=>{
        this.setState({password:target.value});
    }
```

so what is lacking in this component

Comment: You'll have to figure out why `email.value` is undefined.

Comment: thanks, I remove ```.value``` and it worked